# Why does the compiler assume that the value of if let should be `()`?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn translate() -> Option<String> {
    None
}

fn main() {
    let mut found = HashSet::new();

    if let Some(tr) = translate() {
        found.insert(tr);
    }
}
```

It works properly, but when I remove the semicolon after `found.insert(tr)`, I get a compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:9
   |
7  | fn main() {
   |           - expected `()` because of default return type
...
11 |         found.insert(tr)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- help: try adding a semicolon: `;`
   |         |
   |         expected (), found bool
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `bool`
```

It doesn't matter where this code is located or whether it is the last expression of the function.

Why does the compiler assume that the expression inside the curly braces should be `()`?

Comment: I imagine `if` expressions without and `else` must have type `()` since the missing `else` expression implicitly has type `()`. `insert` returns `bool` so the two branches have different types. Adding the semicolon causes your `if` block to have type `()`.

Comment: I think you're right (and it's not very obvious). Adding else {false} also solves the problem.
Do you think compiler should be more flexible here, or works as intended?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/if.html) (emphasis mine):

> The value of the expression is the value of the last expression in whichever branch was chosen. An **`if` without an `else` always results in `()`** as the value.

This gives a constraint on the expression value inside the curly braces.

This is correct since the expression type matches `()`:

```
if let Some(_) = some() {
    ()
};
```

This is correct since there's an `else` statement (and the types between the branches match):

```
if let Some(_) = some() {
    true
} else {
    false
};
```

But this is wrong:

```
if let Some(_) = some() {
    true
};
```

This answer was inspired by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646475/why-does-the-compiler-assume-that-the-value-of-a-function-which-doesnt-return-a#comment62773245_37646475).

Answer (score 0):

When you omit a function's return type, the function actually returns `()`. That is,

```
fn foo() {}
```

is equivalent to:

```
fn foo() -> () {}
```

---

> If I add return (); at the end of the function I still get the same error. So I'm not even sure if that has something to do with a function return value.

An `if let` expression that is used as a statement must return `()`, unless it is the last expression in the function's body, in which case its type must match the function's return type. Since your `if let` doesn't have an `else` clause, its type must be `()`.

Comment: If I add return (); at the end of the function I still get the same error. So I'm not even sure if that has something to do with a function return value.