# Result and if/else/return statements E0308 error

Tags: if-statement, rust, return

Why does the following code raise an error when compiled?

```
fn test(n: i32) -> Result<i32, &'static str> {
    if n == 0 {
        Err("error")
    }
    Ok(n + 1)
}
```

Following is the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:41:9
   |
41 |         Err("error")
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^- help: try adding a semicolon: `;`
   |         |
   |         expected (), found enum `std::result::Result`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `std::result::Result<_, &str>`
```

The following two versions compile without any problem.

1. With `else` statement:

   ```
   fn test(n: i32) -> Result<i32, &'static str> {
       if n == 0 {
           Err("error")
       }
       else {
           Ok(n + 1)
       }
   }
   ```
2. With `return` statement:

   ```
   fn test(n: i32) -> Result<i32, &'static str> {
       if n == 0 {
           return Err("error");
       }
       Ok(n + 1)
   }
   ```

I'm using Rust 1.27.0.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Why does an if without an else always result in () as the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43335193/155423) and [Why does the compiler assume that the value of if let should be `()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37646475/155423) and [return a value from within an if statement in a match statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30812469/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine this simplified code:

```
fn test() -> i32{
    { 1 }
    2
}
```

This fails with the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:2:11
  |
2 |         { 1 }
  |           ^ expected (), found integral variable
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `{integer}`
```

That is because in Rust a full statement must have type `()`. If you want to ignore a value, just adding a `;` converts a value into a statement, and changes the type to `()` discarding the value.

This code compiles:

```
fn test() -> i32{
    { 1; }
    2
}
```

Your example is similar, but the `if` makes things more interesting. If you write:

```
fn test(c: bool) -> i32{
    if c { 1 }
    2
}
```

It will fail, just as before, because the first statement has a type different from `()`. Adding a `;` solves the issue:

```
fn test(c: bool) -> i32{
    if c { 1; }
    2
}
```

Writing an `else` also compiles, because then there is only one statement in the function and its type matches the return type of the function:

```
fn test(c: bool) -> i32{
    if c { 1 }
    else { 2 }
}
```

Note that both branches must have the same type, and no `;` in either.

Adding a `return` will also work, because a return statement has `()` by definition, so any of these will compile:

```
fn test1(c: bool) -> i32{
    if c { return 1; }
    2
}
fn test2(c: bool) -> i32{
    if c { return 1 }
    2
}
fn test3(c: bool) -> i32{
    if c { return 1; }
    else { 2 }
}
fn test4(c: bool) -> i32{
    if c { return 1; }
    else { return 2; }
}
```

Note how the `;` is actually optional in these `return` statements, because it is already of type `()`.